# jms expiration, AMQ->MQ Series

Tags: apache-camel, jms, ibm-mq, amq

We are trying to preserve TimeToLive/JMSExpiration in our messages during moving them from AMQ queue to IBM MQ Series queue, currently we use: jmsBridgeConnectors in AMQ to move the messages but the expiration is not preserved.
I know that AMQ suggests to rather use Camel instead of jmsBridgeConnectors to bridge AMQ to external messaging systems, but I have no experience with Camel.

Did anyone face similar issue and have some working solution, either with jmsBridgeConnectors or Camel?

Many thanks in advance
Best Regards
Lukasz

Answer (score 1):

If you use Camel and its JMS component, then you can turn on `preserveMessageQos` which will then transfer the expiration detail. See more details in the Camel documentation (see the table of the option): http://camel.apache.org/jms

In terms of the JMS bridge, I assume you refer to the AMQ JMS bridge? http://activemq.apache.org/jms-to-jms-bridge.html - I am not sure if you can configure to keep the expiration or not. Others here at SO may know, or you can dive into the source code, or try to ask on the ActiveMQ user mailing list.

Comment: Correct, I am referring to AMQ JMS bridge.